# What is the probability that the sum will be less than $6$ when three fair six-sided dice are thrown?

Tags: probability

Three fair six-sided dice are thrown, and the score is the sum of the three results. What is the probability that the score is less than $6$?

Comment: What are the different ways to add up to $3$, $4$, or $5$, if you count $1+1+2$ as different from $1+2+1$ (say)?  How many different ways are there to roll three dice altogether?

Comment: Are the throws hidden or right before the eyes of the presumed player?

Comment: If you know about random variables you can get a close approximation by assuming the sum on three rolls is $S = X_1 + X_2 + X_3,$ where $X_i$ is the result on the $i$th die, $X_i$ independent. Then $E(X_i) = 3.5,$ $V(X_i)=8.75, E(S) = 10.5,$ and $SD(S) = 2.96.$ Assuming $S\stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(10.5,2.96),$ you can get $P(S < 5.5)\approx 0.046,$ which is very nearly the exact answer $10/216$ obtained by counting outcomes. (The normal approximation is 'pretty good' in the tails of the distribution.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(X<6)$, where $X =$ the sum of $x_1, x_2, x_3 $

In this case, we can simply list out all the outcome such $P(X<6)$

1. $(1,1,1), (1,1,2), \dots, (1,1,3), \dots, (3,1,1).$

Note that each event has the same probability:

2. Find the probability of one event: $P(x_1 \cap x_2 \cap x_3) $

Connecting both 1. and 2. you should be able to go on to the next and final step to solving the problem.

Comment: You need more dots (and commas) on line `1.` to indicate more clearly it is only a partial list. I have made a minor edit. (+1)

Comment: Thanks Bruce. I'm new to mathexchange, as well as writing mathematical text online.